# Can apply in pandas split-apply-combine increase dimension?

Tags: pandas

In [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html), it says that the apply step can be one of aggregation, transformation or filtration. Analogous to aggregation where the dimension is reduced and transformation where dimension does not change, is there a way to apply so that the dimension increases?

For example, instead of using just z-score to standardize (the transformation example in the doc), is there a way to apply a few ways of normalization (z-score, quantile, etc) at once?

Edit:

Thanks for the comments which pointed to agg and flexible apply.

I wonder how flexible the flexible apply can be? See comments below in excerpt from flexible apply [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply):

```
In [119]: grouped = df.groupby('A')['C']

In [120]: def f(group):
   .....:     return pd.DataFrame({'original' : group,
   .....:                          'demeaned' : group - group.mean()})
   .....: 

In [121]: grouped.apply(f)// this works, but df.groupby("A").apply(f) does not
```

Without groupby() but closely related and mentioned in [flexible apply documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply),

> apply on a Series can operate on a returned value from the applied
>   function, that is itself a series, and possibly upcast the result to a
>   DataFrame

If the return value of the applied function is itself a dataframe, can an "upcast" to dataframe with multiindex happen automatically?

Similarly, how flexible can agg() be? In the examples in the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once), the function agg() takes all seems to take a series and return a value.

Comment: Are you asking to [apply more than one function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-multiple-functions-at-once) in your aggregation?

Comment: Yes, you must use `apply` which is very flexible (at a great cost of speed). You can return any sort of dataframe from it in any size and shape. It is aptly named [flexible apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply) in the docs

Comment: @chrisaycock Thanks for the comments! Can you help comment on my follow-up edit?

Comment: @TedPetrou Thanks for the comments! Can you help comment on my follow-up edit?